Contenteditable Div Expands Instead of Adding Scrollbars
I have a contenteditable div with the ID editor. I'm encountering an issue where the editor keeps expanding in height as I add content. I have overflow-y set to auto, but instead of adding scrollbars, the #editor expands in height.
Additionally, if I paste an article from the web or from MS Word, the editor expands in both width and height and does not respect the set width and height.
It works if I give it a fixed width and height in pixels, but I want it to be responsive. Can someone point out what the issue might be?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="list-container"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-header">
            <button id="toggle-button">☰</button>
        </div>
        <div id="content-block">
            <div id="note-tools"></div>
            <div id="inner-content">
                <form id="formNotes">
                    <input id="noteTitle">
                    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#main-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

#list-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0073e6;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toggle-button {
    display: none;
    background-color: #005bb5;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content-block {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#note-tools {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#formNotes {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#noteTitle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#editor {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar, #list-container {
        display: none;
    }

    #toggle-button {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #content {
        margin-left: 0;
        transition: margin-left 0.3s;
    }

    #sidebar.active + #content {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}

link to codepen
https://codepen.io/Oshi-Wijesinghe/pen/KKjvxLj
As you can see in the code pen, if just keep entering on the editor div it does not add scrollbars instead keep expending the div,

I can't see where you have set a max-height for #editor. Also if you want it to be responsive consider using units such as vh.

You have very minor issue you need to assign any fixed height to #editor. In below example I have added height: 50vh. We need to add a fixed height then only overflow will work. If this fixes issue accept it as anwer so it can help people with similar issue.


body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#main-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

#list-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0073e6;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toggle-button {
    display: none;
    background-color: #005bb5;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content-block {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#note-tools {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#formNotes {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#noteTitle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#editor {
  height: 50vh;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar, #list-container {
        display: none;
    }

    #toggle-button {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #content {
        margin-left: 0;
        transition: margin-left 0.3s;
    }

    #sidebar.active + #content {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="list-container"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-header">
            <button id="toggle-button">☰</button>
        </div>
        <div id="content-block">
            <div id="note-tools"></div>
            <div id="inner-content">
                <form id="formNotes">
                    <input id="noteTitle">
                    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae perspiciatis laudantium alias asperiores dolor. Voluptas debitis labore odit asperiores. Incidunt dolores dolor labore adipisci, corrupti dolorem iusto! Maiores perferendis ex quibusdam mollitia quo. Nemo, minus inventore mollitia explicabo facilis, id nisi quidem earum sunt veniam assumenda enim ea exercitationem non pariatur quia reprehenderit iste consequatur molestias corporis accusantium sint deleniti veritatis tempora. Ipsam, corrupti nostrum! Nesciunt, doloribus aliquid! Odio autem officia omnis tempora quibusdam quia ut perspiciatis temporibus quo, nisi, in, facilis minima excepturi magni minus deleniti dignissimos adipisci possimus beatae. Vero dignissimos suscipit assumenda distinctio! Quasi sapiente eius omnis.
                      
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni similique sed, impedit eos amet aspernatur quisquam eveniet illo sapiente ducimus porro doloribus odio consequuntur, excepturi asperiores error cumque, molestias quidem ullam. Reiciendis porro ipsa quo deleniti nostrum consequuntur omnis architecto nam quae ipsam inventore quas sequi harum, doloremque quis delectus hic. Quae in alias debitis necessitatibus maiores quasi sint dolore, quis quibusdam nostrum eum sequi, neque repudiandae. Unde quibusdam magnam reiciendis vero culpa ducimus eligendi quos, assumenda accusamus sunt, deleniti possimus minus eos repellat porro maxime autem illum a, nihil velit sit non eaque officia dicta. Possimus distinctio sequi tenetur at necessitatibus, velit fuga, natus impedit voluptas ipsam minima perspiciatis ea corporis amet rerum voluptatem reiciendis dolorum placeat praesentium. Impedit a excepturi dolor tenetur recusandae perferendis ipsam expedita, inventore delectus saepe suscipit adipisci, explicabo enim iure quos autem at minima similique quaerat veniam cumque officiis maxime. Modi iusto adipisci facere maiores impedit magnam distinctio molestias ipsa. Harum iusto quae, cumque corrupti numquam nobis, dolorem nulla ut debitis reiciendis quia officiis in! Aspernatur sequi dicta quisquam? Nemo, nulla quisquam! Laboriosam sequi odit, officia officiis ut explicabo incidunt aliquam voluptatum perferendis qui. Temporibus accusantium mollitia aperiam quia ex vitae, cupiditate soluta unde?
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>




Thank you for your reply. However still there is issue with width when using in a desktop. do i need to give max-width to fix this issue?

@ally tell me more about width issue so I can suggest some solution.
